# Activerecord relationship joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working in Rails and Activerecord and trying to merge some data from related tables together in my view, here are my models:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reports
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end
```

Each vote has a user and a report.

In my view I need the following, hopefully as easily as possible:

1. a total number of votes for each report from all users
2. a true/false if the user has voted on the particular report

Right now, my basic understanding of ActiveRecord queries only takes me as far as creating a *helper* with the report and the current `user` and than querying for the existence of `report`

Same goes for counting the total number of votes for all users for a `report` as follows:

**Controller**

```
def index
  #this is where I need some help to get the related information into a single
  #object
  @reports = Report.where('...')
end
```

**View**

```
<% @reports.each do |report| %>
    <% if(hasVoted(@current_user.id, report.id)) %>
        <!-- display the 'has voted html' -->
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Helper**

```
def hasVoted(current_user_id, report_id)
    if(Vote.exists?(:user_id => current_user_id, :report_id => report_id))
      true
    else
      false
    end      
end
```

Hope that gives you some insight into helping...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Firstly, please consider naming your method has_voted? instead of hasVoted. Secondly, consider moving that method in the user model.

```
#user.rb
def voted_on?(report_id)
  votes.where(:report_id => report_id).exists?
end
```

Your view will then read

```
<% if current_user.voted_on?(report) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The other question you had was to find the number of votes a report has received. This is simple too. You could do this in your view inside the loop where you iterate over @reports

```
<% vote_count = report.votes.size %>
```

Please keep in mind that his would result in N queries (where N = number of reports). Since you are new to Rails i'm not going to complicate your Reports query in the controller where you fetch you reports to include the vote count (unless you ask me to). But once you are comfortable with what happening in here, thats where you would optimize.

Comment: thank you, so do I need to add an `include` clause in my query? Or will ActiveRecord just make the association based on `Reports` model?

Comment: You dont need to include votes in your query just as yet. We would include votes if we were writing a more complex query which would fetch report information along with vote count in one shot.

Comment: I did a `<%= debug report %>` and it looks like I didn't make my association correctly when I setup the tables, I did it kind of manually adding a `report_id` column to the `Vote` table, once I make the connection correctly, I think your right ActiveRecord should be smart enough to return the related `Votes` records just by querying for `Report`

Comment: did you mean <%= debug report %> since you dont have \@report instance variable, only \@reports (the plural version).

Comment: Ughh..i'm sorry to have assumed you are new to rails, sometimes i'm thinking of a recent previous question when answering another one.

Comment: No, it's fine, you helped me realizing how _ActiveRecord automatically pulls in related records via the :has_many relationships_. Your explanation worked, and I'll move that method out of a helper and into the correct location on the `User model`.